# Unable to drag & drop file on Lubuntu using Pcmanfm-qt

Tags: lubuntu, files, pcmanfm, drag-and-drop

**What is not working?**
*Dragging item from one place, to another bookmarked place/folder, after the drag, nothing happen*

**What is working?**
*Dragging item from one place, to another folder inside the current directory, it will pop up some option says Copy here, Move here, Create symlink here, and Cancel*

**Visualization**
[image: drag item from one place to another bookmarked place]

**System?**

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               quenyan@quemac 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           --------------                    
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64     
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: MacBookAir6,2 1.0           
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.8.0-53-generic          
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 2 hours, 42 mins          
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1824 (dpkg)             
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17                
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1440x900              
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: LXQt                          
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Openbox                       
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Lubuntu Arc             
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Arc-Darker [GTK3]          
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Adwaita [GTK3]             
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: qterminal               
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      Terminal Font: Ubuntu Mono 14     
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       CPU: Intel i7-4650U (4) @ 3.300GH 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: Intel Haswell-ULT            
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 1050MiB / 7901MiB
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using `pcmanfm` ?   as that's not included by default with Lubuntu (it's a deprecated GTK2 program; and was replaced by `pcmanfm-qt` which is Qt5 like the LXQt desktop is).  It might also help me understand if you are specific; dragging from where?  a local folder, network share? and have you tried the Lubuntu manual?  https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/2/2.4/2.4.4/pcmanfm-qt.html

Comment: Ah, sorry for my mistake, I thought that was the same thing, it seems that pcmanfm-qt is the correct one.

Comment: just regular dragging like any other os do, says I navigate to Download folder in `pcmanfm-qt`, and lets say I have `a.jpg` file there, now I drag it to `Picture` folder, which should be located on the left side drop down list, when hovering while dragging the file to the destination `Picture`, it should have the `+` sign, which can mean 2 things, `put the file there` or `make a shortcut here`, well anyway both does not happen when I release the drag, when I navigate to `Picture` folder, no `a.jpg` file exist.

Comment: I wasn't able to find the upstream (github; there is an explanation there) issue relating to this... the easiest option is to use a different file-manager (`dolphin` maybe) when you want to do such tasks.  Note: If I drag a file from ~ and drop in my *Downloads* it asks if I want to copy/move/create-symlink/cancel but I'm using a later release.  The issue I don't believe will be fixed in *focal* thus using an alternative (`dolphin` is what I've tested as it's Qt5 based (but needs KF5), but `thunar` & others work too just using different libs to your desktop)

Comment: thanks for the answer @guiverc, I believe this bug remain unsolved as using alternative does not counted as solved, unless Lubuntu made a move, removing the pcmanfm-qt  and use other file manager as their default. Being light is okay, but being crippled makes the OS bad.

Comment: The issue is resolved (by Lubuntu) with the use of an updated Qt version as I recall... available to you when you upgrade to 20.10, 21.04 or anything later...   Ubuntu 20.04 (*focal*) is stuck using the LTS Qt version it came with, thus the LXQt/KDE cannot be upgraded because of that, so a number of *fixed* issues will remain with *focal* until it reaches EOL.  Security fixes are back-ported, but that does not qualify as a security-fix.